# How can I best combine React and D3 but still use D3 like I always have?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, higher-order-components

I am creating a React application and need to add some custom made D3 charts. I want to incorporate the charts in the application ‘flow’ and make use of the React component life cycle methods, but I also want to be able to just write the D3 code in it’s own way like I’m used to (enter - update - exit pattern and such), without wrapping individual parts of the charts in React components like [vx](https://github.com/hshoff/vx) or [react-d3](http://www.reactd3.org/) is doing.

So far i've found - [react-faux-dom](https://oli.me.uk/2015/09/09/d3-within-react-the-right-way/) which seems really promising, but the project needs to contain as little external dependencies as possible.

Comment: First Google search result: [Interactive Applications with React & D3](https://medium.com/@Elijah_Meeks/interactive-applications-with-react-d3-f76f7b3ebc71)

Comment: Without seeing what you've done we can't advise you on anything. Asking for examples is off topic so we can't do that. Your question is far too broad for the SO platform where one asks specific questions that can be given specific answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Your right. its actually one of the posts I based my own answer on. Just thought I would share my own solution here.

Comment: @Rob I see. I'm still new to the asking questions on StackOverflow so I need to get the hang of it a bit :) Thx for the heads-up

Comment: @marcel-k have you taken a look at `Victory` from FormidableLabs: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory? It's a set of reuseable React components built using `d3` and integrates the two nicely. It can take a lot of the pain away of trying to make the two work together. You can also do what you're proposing and use lifecycle hooks like `componentDidMount` for doing standard `d3` stuff. Take a look at this [blog post](https://parkerziegler.com/senior-research-programming-for-gis/2017/7/6/mapping-in-react-and-d3) for some more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research of my own, I found this can be achieved by creating a [React Higher-Order Component (HOC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for the charts.

The HOC will act like a base / wrapper component, pass through the chart data and enhance any properties if necessary. Using React’s lifecycle methods, it calls similar methods (create, update, destroy) on the chart instance, that can just be written like a ES6 class or maybe a function, as long as it implements the correct methods

```
function withChart(ChartComponent) {
    class ChartHOC extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.chart = new ChartComponent();
        }

        componentDidMount() {            
            this.chart.create(this.container);
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {            
            this.chart.update();
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div className='chartContainer'ref={(el) => { this.container = el; }}></div>);
        }
    }

    return ChartHOC;
}

class BarChart { 
    // Mandatory function when using chartHOC
    create(containerEl) {
        ...
    }

    // Mandatory function when using chartHOC  
    update(props) {
    ...
    }
}

// wrap the barChart with the chartHOC
const Example = withChart(BarChart);
```

I made a fiddle of a stripped down version of a chartHOC and an example of a very simple BarChart that uses the HOC here: https://jsfiddle.net/marcelk/vf51tvzf/

So this approach achieves exactly what I wanted. I can make use of React’s lifecycle methods, pass props the React way and still write D3 code to manage the chart’s behavior, transitions etc.